# Drawing multiple polygons with leaflet in Shiny

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny, polygons, shiny-server

I am struggling to draw multiple polygons in a Shiny app - based on leaflet package.

Here is a non-app output that I wish for:

```
data <- list(
    beam1 = data.frame(lat = c(-115,-125, -125, -115),
               lon = c(32, 32, 45,45)),
    beam2 =     data.frame(lat = c(-100, -111, -111, -100),
                           lon = c(42, 42, 50,50))
)
dataTemp <- do.call(rbind, lapply(data, function(x) rbind(x, NA)))

library(leaflet)
m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()
m %>%
    addPolygons(
        dataTemp[,"lat"],
        dataTemp[,"lon"],
        color = c('red', 'green'), weight = 3
    )
```

However, creating a Shiny app out of it is proving to be difficult - the polygons get plotted and then disappear one by one once a new polygon is plotted. Here is the code I am using. You need to click on 'Draw' to plot polygons
Notice how:
1 - red polygon disappears when green is drawn (after 3 seconds)
2 - the polygons are triangles here, while in the above code they are rectangles.
3 - if you look at code in server.R below, I actually had to flip 'lat' and 'lon' columns to get even remotely correct picture.

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyUI(navbarPage("Beams", id="nav",

    tabPanel("Interactive map",
            div(class="outer",

                leafletMap("map", "100%", 650,
                           options = list(center = c(37.45, -93.85), zoom = 4)),
                actionButton("drawPoints", "Draw")
            )
    )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

data <- list(
    beam1 = data.frame(lat = c(-115,-125, -125, -115),
                       lon = c(32, 32, 45,45)),
    beam2 =     data.frame(lat = c(-100, -111, -111, -100),
                           lon = c(42, 42, 50,50))
)

# server activity
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    map <- createLeafletMap(session, "map")

    observe({

            if(input$drawPoints == 0) {
                return(NULL)
            } else {

                map$clearShapes()

                for (i in seq_along(data)) {
                    map$addPolygon(
                        data[[i]][,"lon"],  # - notice, i had to change lat and lon
                        data[[i]][,"lat"],
                        layerId=c("1"),
                        list( fillOpacity=0.4),
                        list(color = c('red','green')[i])

                    )
                    Sys.sleep(3)  # - this is to see first (red) polygon
                }
            }
        })


})
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: arrived here by chance... so not expert on the topic..As user of shiny I may say that you are not doing it the way I would expect... I suggest you use the renderLeaflet command to generate your output. I have found this article that may be useful for you: http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-leaflet-package-for-online-mapping-in-r/ .

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? Because I probably have one if you're still interested and haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: @ndimhypervol even if OP isn't specifically still looking, your answer could be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

I've updated your code to use leaflet proxies, which is a cleaner way to update existing maps, and is the currently maintained method for doing this in ongoing updates to the `leaflet` package (as far as I know). I switched your "lat" and "lon" in the data.frame to make them correct. I also added the origin point again at the end of your coordinates to complete the shape -- that's why you had triangles and not rectangles. Lastly, I changed the `layerId` for the polygons to `i` to make them different -- that's why they were erasing each other.

I assumed that you want the shapes to be hardcoded, but there are ways to open up the polygon plot selection (or even drawing) to the user. Interesting note: in solving this, learned about the `deferUntilFlush` param in `leafletProxy` -- without this set to `FALSE`, both shapes plot only after `Sys.sleep` is done counting.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyUI(navbarPage("Beams", id="nav",

                   tabPanel("Interactive map",
                            div(class="outer",
                                leafletOutput("map", "100%", 650),
                                actionButton("drawPoints", "Draw")
                            )
                   )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

data <- list(
  beam1 = data.frame(lon = c(-115,-125, -125, -115, -115),
                     lat = c(32, 32, 45, 45, 32)),
  beam2 =     data.frame(lon = c(-100, -111, -111, -100, -100),
                         lat = c(42, 42, 50, 50, 42))
)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  map <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-93.85, 37.45, zoom = 4)
  output$map <- renderLeaflet(map)
  proxy <- leafletProxy("map", deferUntilFlush = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$drawPoints, {
    proxy %>% clearShapes()
    for (i in seq_along(data)) {
      proxy %>% addPolygons(
        data[[i]][,"lon"],
        data[[i]][,"lat"],
        layerId=i,
        opacity=0.4,
        color = c('red','green')[i]
      )
      Sys.sleep(2)  # - this is to see first (red) polygon
    }
  })
})
```